# Angularjs checkbox not binding to initial value

Tags: angularjs, checkbox

Why does angular and the checkbox model not bind to the checked="checked". The checkbox is unset once angular loads. 
eg: http://jsfiddle.net/5CZ74/2/

```
<div ng-app>
   <form>
       <input type="checkbox" ng-model="redirect" checked="checked">
       <input type="text" ng-disabled="redirect==false">
   </form>
</div>
```

When my form loads I am setting it enabled or disabled on the server as per server entity. How do I get the angular model to correctly bind to this value to enable or disable the input text field.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You have not defined `redirect` in your model anywhere, so it is undefined, and thus falsy. This is why the the checkbox is not checked. If you want it checked you need to add `redirect` to your model and set it to true. You need to have a controller and do this:

```
$scope.redirect = true;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/5CZ74/3/

Comment: So the issue is that the model is still not correctly initialized from the server. With your solution the checkbox is always checked. I want it to be checked if ```checked="checked``` and unchecked if that does not exist.

Comment: The point of angular is that your view (the checkbox) is driven from the model ($scope.redirect). Set the value of `$scope.redirect` based on whether or not you want the checkbox to be checked. If the value is `true`, the checkbox will be checked. If the value is `false`, the checkbox will be unchecked. You can even change what values trigger it being checked and unchecked. See http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:input.checkbox